# Can't select next row in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, keydown

here's my code :

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button4.PerformClick();
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
    {
        int R = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        R++;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(R, textBox1.Text, pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox3.Image, pictureBox6.Image, label2.Text);
        itemPhrase();

        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
        dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
        dataGridView1.Rows[R].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.Focus();
    }
}
```

this only select the row i wanted but i can't Edit it,

[image]

it change the row before it.

[image]

so how to Edit the row i selected?

Comment: Make your question to be more clear!

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[g2].Cells[0];